# Reordering array into arrayList at a certain position

Tags: java, arrays, string, date, arraylist

I am trying to reformat some strings that are dates. Some of them have the year at the beginning and I would like those to have their year be at the end. I also want to standardize the separator character to an underscore.

Example input:

```
07_April_2008
16_05_2012
2016-01-28
14/12/2009
```

Desired output:

```
07_April_2008
16_05_2012
01_28_2016
14_12_2009
```

Here's my first attempt, , but I get an error when I do this:

```
public String format(String date) {
    String[] format = null;
    date = date.replace("-", "_");
    date = date.replace("/", "_");
    if (date.contains("_")) {
        format = date.split("_");
        // new arrayList to add rearrangement to
        ArrayList<String> formatNew = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
            if (format[i].matches("\\d{4}")) {
                formatNew.add(2, format[i]);
            } else {
                formatNew.add(format[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

This produces the error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0

I think the year is being picked up fine but the other two elements in the array not.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The exception tells you exactly what is wrong; you are trying to access index **2**; within an array of length 0. In other words: dont assume that `date.split()` creates an array with three elements - check it to be sure. And why do you need other people in order to figure: "maybe i should print out some trace statements to see what is going or; or heck, run it in a debugger to see what happens for each value"?!

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing and formatting dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it as a String problem:

```
List<String> dates; // given this
dates = dates.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\W", "_")) // anything not a letter or number becomes _
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(\\d{4})_(.*)", "$2_$1")) // reorganise leading year dates
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you just want to format a date string:

```
str.replaceAll("\\W", "_").replaceAll("(\\d{4})_(.*)", "$2_$1")
```

If you want to preserve the separator (only changed to underscore to make your code work):

```
str.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(.)(.*)", "$3$2$1")
```

Comment: Simple is beautiful. Didn't need the collection either. Just plain ol' replace all

Comment: @SebastianZeki Thanks. I've added another approach to the end of my answer that may simplify further depending on your final goal.

Answer (score 1):

From Java doc

**Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).**

Below is `ArrayList.add(index,E)` method source code

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
if (index > size || index < 0)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
    "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);
...
```

so it is clear, if the `index` is greater than the `size` or negative it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Have a look at the [DateFormatUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateFormatUtils.html) it has many standard date formats, with that you can format dates